# Sending automated email on database update using AWS

Tags: mysql, email, amazon-web-services, cross-platform

I have a cross platform app built that uses Amazon AWS to manage the backend. I have a MySQL database created that sends and receives data to and from.the app via API calls.

This is working perfect.

On the app I have a from that users can fill in. One of the questions relates to the severity of an action e.g. high, medium and low. Once the user completes and submits the form, the data is sent to MySQL database - again, working 100%.

However, based on the answer of the question re. severity, I need to automate an email to a relevant person. E.g. if the answer was high, an email should automatically be triggered to a person.

Using the mobile OS's built in email functionality (I.e. using sendto: function) is not an option as users might not have this configured and it's not user friendly for my user base.

Is there a way I can trigger generic emails automatically from Amazon AWS if the relevant field on MySQL database is updated with a specified value?

I have no idea where to start with this or if there is a better/easier way.

Comment: This can't be easily done with MySQL. It sounds like you have an API server sitting between the mobile app and the database. Can't you trigger the email from the API server?

Comment: Note that if you switched from MySQL to Aurora (which is MySQL compatible) you would be able to use AWS Lambda functions with database triggers, which would be able to make use of Amazon's SES service to send emails.

Comment: Thanks a million. Think I was trying to over-complicate it too much. Sending the reply from the API server is the easiest solution definitely. If you make this the answer I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in commends you can send that email in layer between your front end and db.. Other option is migrating from MySQL to Aurora.
Third Option is that create a cronjob on some Unix server like every minute which queries this table to see if any new record in last one minute and send an email using sendmail or mutt.